# AJAX Python Call Definition

Tags: python, ajax, parameters, flask, call

I want to call a definition that is located in Python with a parameter, using AJAX. The web framework I'm using is Flask.

In my `test.py` file:

`def example(param):`

In my JS file

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: "test.py"
 //pass param here?
});
```

Comment: Just add `data: "data=yourdata"` within that block...? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: "test.py"
 data: {
    param: param
}
});
```

make sure to include your CSRF token. You can learn more about it here http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/3/

you can add this to your js code.

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks good, but I'm using Flask and got the error `Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. `

Comment: Still getting the same error :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-but-im-loading-a-co